# Cannot send Json Data on Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am sending stringify code on Controller via $.ajax,getting 404 error.
My Stringify Data is below

```
{
  "KeywordID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
  "Name": "EvaluateExpression",
  "OutputType": "Double",
  "Description": "To Evaluate the given expression",
  "AssociatedMethod": "method_Eval",
  "KeywordType": "SystemKeyword",
  "KeywordClass": "Mathematical Operation",
  "PluginID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "PluginName": "SystemKeyword",
  "OutputDescription": "Returns the result of evaluated expression.",
  "Deprecation_Reason": "",
  "KeywordInputParameterDTOs": [
    {
      "Arg_ID": "9d617217-f5bd-4e2e-8df6-84c5319c353f",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand1",
      "description": "Operand1",
      "ENUM_DataType": "Double",
      "Position": 0
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "841541ca-2b8e-4345-966a-7dcb1510deab",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand2",
      "description": "Operand2",
      "ENUM_DataType": "String",
      "Position": 1
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "09c55ad7-8902-4706-9698-d8d30787fd46",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand3",
      "description": "Operand3",
      "ENUM_DataType": "Double",
      "Position": 2
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "95f14ec3-c22d-45de-9117-82803b8c425c",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand4",
      "description": "Operand4",
      "ENUM_DataType": "String",
      "Position": 3
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "b4783adf-bf05-4f81-a83c-532f78f305fc",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand5",
      "description": "Operand5",
      "ENUM_DataType": "Double",
      "Position": 4
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "fbcce45c-d490-4db8-9726-0200d64eaf21",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand6",
      "description": "Operand6",
      "ENUM_DataType": "String",
      "Position": 5
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "2094021e-cf89-4145-a962-9601e695c11d",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand7",
      "description": "Operand7",
      "ENUM_DataType": "Double",
      "Position": 6
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "f3044286-bbbf-41fd-a400-a61675d3d981",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand8",
      "description": "Operand8",
      "ENUM_DataType": "String",
      "Position": 7
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "5b096737-ad8f-4c21-bf30-accf67c21cde",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand9",
      "description": "Operand9",
      "ENUM_DataType": "Double",
      "Position": 8
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "f0f656ae-0adf-4646-a94a-13cd9e3925f7",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand10",
      "description": "Operand10",
      "ENUM_DataType": "String",
      "Position": 9
    },
    {
      "Arg_ID": "c33e4a37-26d3-4e44-a1fb-897d16e3e31c",
      "Keyword_ID": "fb66aacc-c643-43fa-9da1-d6dc714cdeab",
      "Name": "Operand11",
      "description": "Operand11",
      "ENUM_DataType": "Double",
      "Position": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

and my AJAX code is here

```
function demo(data) {
    debugger

    var treeBinding =arrayToObjectString(data) 

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Flow/demo',
        type: "GET",
        data: { dd: treeBinding },
        success: function (res) {

        },
        error: function (error) {
            //alert('error : ' + json.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

when ever I am trying to post only on this Data Sample,I am  getting 404 Error. Please advise me some solution .

Answer (score 0):

Try send:

JSON.stringify(yourData)

Comment: I suggest you to attach the calling row, and the function at server-side

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the url in ajax is the same in code behind. This is one main reason for getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` and `data:treeBinding` like following. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
function demo(data) {
    var treeBinding =arrayToObjectString(data) 

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Flow/demo',
        type: "GET",
        data: treeBinding,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        success: function (res) {

        },
        error: function (error) {
            //alert('error : ' + json.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```